# How to install torch==0.3.1 in python=3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation, version

I am trying to install deepmatcher package in python 3.6. To let this package to run in python you need have a `torch==0.3.1` version. So I am trying to install `torch==0.3.1` by running :

```
pip install torch==0.3.1
```

Error during installation:

> Collecting torch==0.3.1 
>   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==0.3.1 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==0.3.1

I even tried installing it using "peterjc123" package but still unable to uninstall it.

Answer (score 11):

`torch 0.3.1` is not listed official anymore. To install `torch 0.3.1` one can either build it by source or using a `whl` file for the specific version.

## Using a whl file

`whl` files can be found [here](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html) provided by [pytorch](http://pytorch.org)

The downloaded file can then be installed with `pip install [path to downloaded file]`

---

## Build by source

To build torch by source one can checkout the desired version via `git`

`git checkout v[version number]`

For torch==0.3.1 this would be `git checkout v0.3.1`

After this follow the install instructions provided by README.md

---

More information can be found at: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

Comment: Can I do this for python3.7? Each whl file says its not supported by this platform.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have right python installed for you os architecture or 
create a virtual env using conda and then try installing its better this way